# Error in php using curl_init()

Tags: php, curl

I'm completely newbie in PHP.

I have tried example code from [this site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php). but it gives following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\g\test1.php on line 3
```

Am I missing something? It says undefined function curl_init() so where should I define it?

Code:-

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: curl module is probably not enabled, enable it in your php.ini

Comment: @tradyblix: how to enable it?

Comment: you should check if you have curl enabled in you phpinfo();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using xampp as for your error shows it, locate `php.ini` in xampp directory probably located in `C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini` and search for `;extension=php_curl.dll` remove the `;` to uncomment it. Restart xampp.

Comment: I only guessed for `XAMPP` location, I was using `WAMP` atm ;)

Comment: @Arvin: yes its `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`. But one can manage dirs.

Answer (score 1):

[What is your Xampp version?](http://www.yunuscse.com/2010/03/12/how-enable-curl-in-xampp/)

If your version is >= 1.7.1 then follow the following instruction:-

1. Open ..\xampp\php\php.ini
2. Uncomment the following line on your php.ini file by removing the semicolon.

> ;extension=php_curl.dll

1. Restart your apache server

Otherwise, follow following instruction:-

1. Open the following files-

> ..\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
>
> ..\xampp\php\php.ini
>
> ..\xampp\php\php4\php.ini

2) Uncomment the following line on your php.ini file by removing the semicolon.

> ;extension=php_curl.dll

3) Restart your apache server.

Answer (score 0):

check if curl is enable or not

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on Windows and don't have the curl extension enabled. Please read: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php. You need to find `php_curl.dll`, put it in your extension directory and load it from your php.ini